# EntityFeamework contexts connections? Why MSDTC comes into play?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, msdtc

Here's what I do:

> 1. Create transaction scope with isolation level - read commited.
> 2. Create instance of class DataServiceContext ( where DataServiceContext : SessionContext : DbContext).
> 3. Create instance of SessionContext in OnMaterialized event in DataServiceContext (don't ask why).

When I try to get a single record from my session context (created in step 3), I am getting MSDTC error.

Here's the thing. I am not interested in using MSDTC (I know how to make it work using MSDTC). I really have NO IDEA why having the same and only connection string in the application, the transaction gets promoted to distributed transaction, while it should not.

Here are the two connection strings from two contexts (from step 1 and step 2):

```
data source=.;initial catalog=TEST;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework

data source=.;initial catalog=TEST;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

I would really appreciate if someone helped me understand the situation here.

Best
Piotr Kołodziej

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: Did you get any solution of this issue? I am also getting this error but i don't want to start MSDTC service.

Comment: @Sunny If you want to avoid MSDTC, simply add `Enlist=false` to the connectionstring. Read more about it [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720033(v=vs.71).aspx)